# omiagent: is stopped showing stop state

Tags: rhel, monitoring

I am getting the error while running the scxadmin service on **RHEL 6.9**.

```
~]# scxadmin -status
omiserver: is running
omiagent: is stopped
```

I have checked logs but logs are showing empty.

```
]# pwd
/var/opt/omi/log

]# ls -l omiagent.root.root.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Feb 6 00:05 omiagent.root.root.log
```

Sudoer file entry :

```
s-scomeco ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL

]# rpm -qa | grep -i scx
scx-1.5.1-256.el6.x86_64
```

Can you let me know how can I start the omiagent service on the server?

Comment: welcome to U&L, what does man page for scxadmin says ?

Comment: man page is not available for scxadmin command. scxadmin is scom monitoring service. which is use for "scxadmin {-start|-stop|-restart|-status}  [all|cimom|provider]"

Comment: do you have `/var/opt/microsoft/scx/log/omiserver.log` and is there anything interesting in it? Is there a `/var/opt/microsoft/scx/run/omiserver.pid` with a PID in it?

Comment: 2018/07/05 08:13:57: WARNING: wsman: authentication failed for user [username]. I checked that user name and passwored and mentioned the correct login details in scom but I don't know why it's mention authentication failed in logs.

Comment: The correct password is also set in the SCOM profiles? The user is not locked on the RHEL side?

Comment: Do you get the same result if you restart the agent? `/etc/init.d/scx-cimd stop; /etc/init.d/scx-cimd start`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I tried the start and stop the service using above command but still it's showing omiagent stop.

~]# scxadmin -status
omiserver: is running
**omiagent: is stopped**

~]# /etc/init.d/scx-cimd stop
Shutting down Microsoft SCX CIM Server:                    [  OK  ]

~]# scxadmin -status
omiserver: is stopped
omiagent: is stopped


~]# /etc/init.d/scx-cimd start
Starting Microsoft SCX CIM Server:                         [  OK  ]

~]# scxadmin -status
omiserver: is running
**omiagent: is stopped**

Answer (score -1):

Please try to delete the current entry from SCOM and rediscover agent.
Please read below link for more information:

http://draith.azurewebsites.net/?p=351

Comment: If the link says anything pertinent, please quote that portion here. Rediscovering the agent is a decent suggestion, but a bare link "for more information" is not useful if/when that link moves or expires. Thank you!